# Avoid browser autocomplete form feature when clicking on buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form that contains a lot of duplicate textboxes. I have a button called "Copy" that simply copies values from certain textboxes to another.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="copycorporate">Copy</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#copycorporate').button();

$('#copycorporate').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#txt_streetadd').val( $('#txt_corp_address').val() );
    $('#txt_suitefloor').val( $('#txt_corp_suite').val() );

})
```

Now depending on the browser, in this case Firefox 6.0, it prompts the user if they would like to save the form information (usually this happens after a submission). How do I avoid triggering the autocomplete feature when by users simply click on a non-submit utility button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
autocomplete="off"
```

in your input, probably

Comment: I want it off only when the user clicks on THAT button, not the whole form. If the user submits the form, he should be prompted for an autocomplete if he chooses so.

Answer (score 1):

what about adding the attribute like this?

```
$('#txt_streetadd').val( $('#txt_corp_address').val() ).attr("autocomplete","off");
```